# How to prepare Pandas df for Venn diagram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe as follows:

```
+-----+-----------+
| ID  | VALUE     |
+-----+-----------+
| A   | Today     |
+-----+-----------+
| A   | Yesterday |
+-----+-----------+
| B   | Tomorrow  |
+-----+-----------+
| C   | Tomorrow  |
+-----+-----------+
| D   | Today     |
+-----+-----------+
| D   | Tomorrow  |
+-----+-----------+
| E   | Today     |
+-----+-----------+
| E   | Yesterday |
+-----+-----------+
| E   | Tomorrow  |
+-----+-----------+
```

I want to get counts of each ID's "overlap", as I want to construct a Venn diagram from this data.

E.g. in this case, 2 IDs are in 'Today' as well as in 'Tomorrow'. 2 IDs are also in both 'Today' and 'Yesterday'.

How do I go about doing this? I've tried various combinations of `value_counts` and `group_by`, but I've had no luck coming up with something intelligent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` to get the dummies, then matrix product to see cooccurrences:

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['ID'],df['VALUE'])

pair_intersection = s.T @ s
all_three = s.ne(0).all(1)
```

Then, `pair_intersection` looks like:

```
VALUE      Today  Tomorrow  Yesterday
VALUE                                
Today          3         2          2
Tomorrow       2         4          1
Yesterday      2         1          2
```

Then counts of two overlapping groups can be extracted using `pair_intersection.at['Today', 'Tomorrow']`.

`all_three` is

```
ID
A    False
B    False
C    False
D    False
E     True
dtype: bool
```

And thus the number of instances that fall in all three groups is `sum(all_three)`